# Why is my translation of $\exists{x}\,(C(x) \rightarrow F(x))$ into an English sentence wrong?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

Let $\text{C(x): x is a comedian}$ and $\text{F(x): x is funny}$

Let $$\alpha:\quad\exists{x}\,(C(x) \rightarrow F(x))$$ and the domain consists of all people.

I needed to translate $\alpha$ into English so what I did was I looked at when $\beta:\; C(x) \rightarrow F(x)$ is true. There are 2 cases for that:

1. $C(x)$ is false and $F(x)$ is either true or false
2. $C(x)$ is true and $F(x)$ is true.

Using this, I translated it as follows:
There is a comedian that is funny $\textit{(referring to case 2)}$ or there is no comedian. $\textit{(case 1)}$

The solution in the book is:
There exists a person such that if they are a comedian then they are funny.

My professor told me that the way I translated it was wrong.

Why is my translation wrong?

Comment: The book solution is pretty horrible. The only way to understand its meaning in English would be to translate it _back_ to symbolic logic first.

Comment: I am wondering if this is a typo. $\forall x(C(x)\to F(x))$ makes sense. So does $\exists x (C(x) \land F(x)$. In math, we don't usually have existential generalizations of implications as above. If not a typo, I suggest first applying the rule $A\to B\equiv \neg A \lor B$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider a world with no people. Then there is no comedian, so your translation is correct. However, the statement is false because there doesn't exist anyone, in particular no one who satisfies $C(x) \rightarrow F(x)$.

To correct your answer, you could say that in case 1, there is someone who is not a comedian.

Comment: So There is some comedian that is funny or there is someone that is not a comedian would be correct, right?

Answer (score 4):

The domain is of *people*, not commedians.

$\exists x~(\lnot C(x)\lor F(x))$ would read as "There *is* some person who is not a commedian or is funny."

Although equivalent, $\exists x~(C(x)\to F(x))$ more directly translates as "There is some person who would be a commedian only if they were funny."

Comment: Would the following be correct? - There is some comedian that is funny or there is someone that is not a comedian.

Comment: Well, yes, it is an *equivalent* statement.